# Kivy garden matplotlib buildozer

Tags: matplotlib, kivy

I have an app which was successfully packaged for android using python 2 and buildozer. I ammended the program adding the matplotlib garden module using 'garden install --app matplotlib' into the main app directory. It runs fine on pydroid and ubuntu, but crashes after packaging on android. I've added regular matplotlib python library to requirements in .spec file and tried putting matplotlib into the garden requirements also. Should I not add the garden matplotlib to kivy garden requirements in spec file if the garden module is already installed in the main app dir? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ben Yes, apparently matplotlib and buildozer are incompatible at this time. Kivy has it's own garden graph program which seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and would have dropped kivy altogether, until I caught the workaround described here on [github](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1226). It's also referenced in comments on this answer here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887380/kivy-app-crash-in-android-but-not-in-pc-buildozer-keyerror-kivy-garden-matpl). As I saw it, the crash occurred due to the statement `from kivy.garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivyAgg`, and the problem isn't obvious from any of the messages in the android logfiles.